# lwjgl - Editor Viewport

Tags: java, opengl, editor, viewport, lwjgl

I'm working on a project with lwjgl and I've gone pretty far in what concerns progress. Now I need to create an editor so my mapper can start making maps and to make my debugging life easier.
To do a decent editor I need a user interface and at least one viewport.

If you search for Unreal Editor (tm) in google, you'll know what I'm talking about. The problem is I have no idea of how to achieve something like that.

**Edit:** It's a top down 3d game. The only thing I need to know is how to make opengl (lwjgl) render to a specific region of the window instead of using the whole window.

So ye, I only need to know how to tell OpenGL to render to a specific region of the window, I know how to do the rest.

Comment: You should provide more information about how your game works so people can help you with a more suitable map editor.

Comment: I figured that information wasn't needed because I'm not really asking for an editor, but only a way of having opengl render to a specific region on my window.

Comment: Are you just looking for glViewport?

Comment: No. glViewport still makes opengl use the whole window, the only thing it does is render to a region of that whole space used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try glScissor you can find it in `org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11` it will allow you to render content in a specified area and anything outside it will be cut off, it's great for scrolling areas!

You also need to enable `GL_SCISSOR_TEST` before using it and then disable after using `glEnable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST)` and `glDisable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST)`

Comment: Not really what I wanted, but it's close enough. Thanks :D